# Where can I ask about Pastebin as it relates to Google indexing?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I have the following question:

> If I make a Pastebin post of my assignment and enough people Google keywords of that assignment, can those links show up in Google? Or is it a slim to none chance? I want to put all my assignments in links and post them on a website portfolio but I don't want to if every single person will see it that ever tries to Google the keywords in it.
>
> actually I just googled an old assignment along with the words pastebin and it showed up.. is there any alternative to pastebin that has a private option that blocks search engines from viewing them? like only able to view it with a direct link? but not necessarily requiring a password to view it.

Could you recommend a Q&A section on Stack Exchange where I could get an answer for this type of question?

Comment: If I had to guess, I'd say you could maybe ask this on [Web Apps](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), though I'm not sure if the SEO part of it would make it off-topic or not.

Comment: i posted but yeah it kinda would be off topic so probably wont get any answers

Comment: I just figured out that "unlisted" on pastebin stops it from showing up on google searches. Woo! :D nevermind

Comment: however i also figured out you only get 25 unlisted pastes without having to pay for it..